# little information needed in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

i am working on a project which is airways ticketing.

i am able to display the final ticket to the user but how can i give user the ability to print  it when he/she clicks on print button.

please help..

```
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #main {
position:absolute;

top:100px;
width:100%;
height:250px;
z-index:1;
}
#submit {
position:absolute;

top:300px;
width:100%;
height:42px;
z-index:2;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main" align="center">
<?PHP
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("cmc");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$r=mysql_query("select * from manifest where transid=".$id);
$d=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
?>

<table width="800" border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center">HORIZON AIRWAYS PASSENGER TICKET</td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="3" align="center">PNR NUMBER: </td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $d["pnrno."]; ?></td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="3" align="center"> PASSENGER'S NAME:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $d["name"]; ?></td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="3" align="center">DATE OF ISSUE:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?PHP 
ini_set('date.timezone','asia/calcutta');
echo date("d/m/y"); ?></td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="3" align="center">TIME OF ISSUE:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?PHP  
echo date("h/i/s"); ?></td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="3" align="center">DATE OF JOURNEY:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $d["day"]."-".$d["month"]."-".$d["year"]; ?>         </td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center">NOT TRANSFERRABLE</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">PASSENGER NAME:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $d["name"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">SECTOR:</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $d["sector"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="134" align="center">FLIGHT #</td>
<td width="132" align="center">CLASS</td>
<td width="112" align="center">DATE</td>
<td width="130" align="center">DEP. TIME</td>
<td width="132" align="center">ARR. TIME</td>
<td width="120" align="center">STATUS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $d["flight_no."]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $d["class"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $d["name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $d["departure"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $d["arrival"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "confirm"; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
<div id="submit" align="center">
<form name="form1" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Print" name="submit"/>
</form>
</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note this isn't PHP as much Javascript.

Comment: See This Link, it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570323/how-to-give-a-print-to-printer-in-php-gtk

Answer (score 2):

Printing has to be done on the client side, not the server side.  This shouldn't be a form (I would actually make it a link).  The simplest method:

```
<input type="submit" value="Print" onclick="print(); return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the print event bij using the javascript function: `window.print()`.

Example:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">print page</a>
```

### TIP!

Use a print CSS to tell the browser what to print! That way the user doesn't waste paper ;)

Example including a print CSS stylesheet: `<style type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />`

More info about CSS print stylesheets: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke printing via javascript using [print](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) method

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</A>
```

You might want to hide certain elements in page when printing it. For that you can use css like so:

```
@media print {
   .non-printable { display: none; }
  }
```

And then give non-printable class to those elements that you don't want printed.

Comment: can you explain a little more how to hide elements while printing

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/ should tell you what you need to know about print css files. They're really quite simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct that this would be done with

`<a href="javascript:window.print()">print ticket</a>`

You will also probably want to create a separate CSS style for the print version that strips out unnecessary graphics.  You can also add manual page breaks in case there are individual boarding passes or something.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```